# JS function needs to run parallel on instances

Tags: jquery, loops, iterator

In this function the images are rotated correctly. But I need it to work for a few instances of class `.svg`. In the moment it passes trough the instances. Need help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = $('.svg > img');
  var numImages = images.length;
  var innerLoopIterator = 0;
  var outerLoopIterator = 0;
  var numOuterLoops = 20;
  var stayTime = 800;

  images.hide();

  function rotateImage() {
    images.eq(innerLoopIterator)
      .fadeIn()
      .delay(stayTime)
      .queue(function(next) {
        innerLoopIterator += 1;
        if (innerLoopIterator >= numImages) {
          innerLoopIterator = 0;
          outerLoopIterator += 1;
        }
        if (outerLoopIterator < numOuterLoops) {
          next();
          rotateImage();
        }
      })
      .fadeOut();
  }
  rotateImage();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="svg">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/160x120/000/fff&text=pic+1" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/160x120/000/fff&text=pic+2" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/160x120/000/fff&text=pic+3" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/160x120/000/fff&text=pic+4" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/160x120/000/fff&text=pic+5" />
</div>
```

Comment: All you need to do is remove the 'loopIterator' logic and call the animation on `images` directly, without using `eq()`.

Comment: You can make all variables local and pass them to function as parameters. Then you just need call it with different selectors for each instance.

Comment: @Rory: But without die LoopIterator logic the instances cant rotate the images per instance. Or do I overlook something?

Comment: ... That's what your question is asking to do, though...?

Comment: Well, in each .svg are a bunch of img. I need to cycle through the images. That works. But only on one instance of .svg

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gztqhzj8/